# Last else if statement not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple if statement to change the background colour of a div depending on the number entered within another div. I've tried making a few changes to the code but can never get the last else if statement to work.

```
if ($(".pacenumber").text() <= "59") {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
else
if ($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60" < "80") {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
else
if ($(".pacenumber").text() >= "80") {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

If the number entered is <= "59" the div changes to red correctly.

If the number entered is >= "60" and < "80" the div changes to yellow correctly.

If the number entered is >= "80" the div stays yellow and will not change to green.

Is there a possible solution to get the last if statement working?

Comment: >= "60" < "80" is not valid and you are comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: The last statement in a multiple if/if else is else

Comment: question: you're comparing what the code suggests are numbers. Why are you comparing strings instead? For instance: the string "7"is **not** less than "63", because we're comparing strings, and in text anything starting with "6" comes before anything starting with "7". This code is going to be a source of bugs if you don't wrap those `...text()` calls in a `parseInt(...)` and then compare with real numbers instead.

Comment: Your just missing part of the second statement. It should be `$(".pacenumber").text() >= "60" && $(".pacenumber").text() < "80"` (plus as people above say, comepare numbers, not strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use this syntax to check if a value is in a range:

```
if ($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60" < "80") {
```

This is interpreted as if you'd written

```
if (($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60") < "80") {
```

`($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60")` will return either `true` or `false`. When you compare a boolean with a string, `false` is converted to `"0"` and `true` converts to `"1"`. Both of these are less than `"80"`, so that test will always be true.

Just use

```
else
if ($(".pacenumber").text() < "80") {
```

You don't need to test if it's at least `"60"` because the previous `if` takes care of all the values less than this. If it gets to this `else if`, it must be `>= "60"`.

Comment: Excellent explanation of why the final if is never reached.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! I've not used javascript much so completely forgot how the if statements worked.

Answer (score 0):

As said by the commenters, the second branch is missing a part and you should compare using numbers not string.

```
function tt(t) {
   if (t <= 59) {
      return 1;
   } 
   else
   if (t >= 60 && t < 80) {
      return 2;
   }
   else
   if (t >= 80) {
      return 3;
   }
}
```

Using strings (as "80", "60"), calling the function `tt("080")` would return 1. Using the definition above, it returns 3.

Comment: The last entry in multiple else-if statements is always 'else'. This tells JS the query is being terminated and it expects the closing braces - or a lead-in to another subroutine with a left brace.

Comment: Nope. In this case yes, the last one could be replaced by an 'else', but not this one :
`if (var == "a") {} else if (var == "b") {} else if (var == "c") {}`
If last one is changed to 'else' instead, than all the values except 'a' and 'b' will do this code, which is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simply the following:

```
var pace = parseInt($(".pacenumber").text(), 10);
var color = "green";

if (pace < 60) {
    color = "red";
} else if (pace  < 80) {
    color = "yellow";
}
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

note the lack of repeated calls to jquery and the single place where the background colour is set

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60" < "80") {
```

to

```
($(".pacenumber").text() >= "60" && $(".pacenumber").text() < "80") {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($(".pacenumber").text() <= 59) {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "red";
} 
else
if ($(".pacenumber").text() >= 60 < 80) {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
else
if ($(".pacenumber").text() >= 80) {
document.getElementById("paceheader").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
else{}
}
```

// I added a null terminator to close the function properly. Irrational values will result in no change to color. Be careful on 'numbers' vs. text numbers. I removed the quotes so they become literal numbers. Makes the math much easier.